# How do I change the size of a Button in ASP.NET?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, razor, submit

Normally in ASP.NET Core from what I have seen, there are two types of buttons, those which represent a Link/Action, and those which are a "Submit Button". And always the buttons which are Submit are much larger than the buttons which are just a Link.

This type of code for a button which is a Link, I use:

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
LINK BUTTON
 </a>

<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit" asp-action="Create" asp-route-id="">
 ANOTHER LINK BUTTON
</a>
```

And the code I use for the Submit Buttons is like this one:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <input type="submit" value="BIGG BUTTON" class="btn btn-primary" />
</div>
```

How can I make the size of all my buttons to be the same? And I obviously meant the fact that the Submit buttons are thicker, since I would like to have all my buttons with the same thickness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use the `<a></a>` tag to submit your form instead of the `<input/>` tag so the styles are preserved. You just call submit-form with juery like below.

```
<form asp-action="CreateForm" method="post">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary submit-form">
        Big Button
    </a>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("click", ".submit-form", function () {
            var form = $(this).closest("form");
            form.submit();
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `btn-sm` class attributes from the small buttons.